# How to convert numbers in a string, into a hash

Tags: ruby, string, hash

Given a string, such as `"ABCD 100"`, what is the most efficient way to convert it into `{"ABCD": 100}`, where `"ABCD"` is the key and `100` is an integer and the value?

Comment: Is your string always separated just by one space?, is it only one string or could be an array of strings?, you could add more info.

Comment: _"what is the most efficient way"_ – in which regard?

Comment: @SebastiánPalma, yes - the string is separated by one space.

Comment: @Stefan, in the sense that it is the most idiomatic way in Ruby (if that makes sense).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that you have more than one key-value pair, you can combine `split`, `each_slice` and `map`:

```
"ABCD 100 EFG 200".split
                  .each_slice(2)
                  .map {|k, v| [k.to_sym, v.to_i]}.to_h
#=> {:ABCD=>100, :EFG=>200}
```

Or with `scan` and groups:

```
"ABCD 100 EFG 200".scan(/([A-Z]+)\s([0-9]+)/)
                  .map! {|k, v| [k.to_sym, v.to_i]}.to_h
#=> {:ABCD=>100, :EFG=>200}
```

Use regex according to your actual issue, it is just an instance.

Answer (score 2):

If that is the exact format I'd do

```
key, value = "ABCD 100".split
{key.to_sym => value.to_i}
```

If you're looking for a one-liner

Since ruby 2.4.0

```
["ABCD 100".split].to_h.each_with_object({}) { |(k, v), memo| memo[k.to_sym] = v.to_i }
```

From ruby 2.4.0

```
["ABCD 100".split].to_h.transform_values!(&:to_i)
```

Comment: `transform_values!` is preferable here.

Comment: What do you mean? We have no variables

Comment: Note: in the OP's example, the key should end up as a `Symbol`, not a `String`.

Comment: I mean mutate existing hash is better than creating a new one. You've already had one after `to_h`, why do you need one more?

Comment: Thanks to both of you. I don't know if I have a valid alternative to `transorm_values!` for the key though :/

Answer (score 0):

If your pattern is string like "key value", you can use String#split. It takes a string and returns an Array of substrings delimited by a separator. If you don't give a separator, the default one is spaces.

```
def insert_values_from_string_into_hash(to_be_parsed_string, hash)
  string_key, value = to_be_parsed_string.split
  hash[string_key] = value
  hash
end   

insert_values_from_string_into_hash("ABCD 100", {})
```